# Loading a theme and fontifying in batch mode

Tags: faces, themes, batch-mode

Loading a theme in batch mode seems to not set face attributes:

```
$ emacs -Q --eval "(load-theme 'tango t)" \
           --eval "(prin1 (face-attribute 'font-lock-keyword-face :foreground)))"
"#346604"

$ emacs --batch -Q --eval "(load-theme 'tango t)" \
                   --eval "(prin1 (face-attribute 'font-lock-keyword-face :foreground)))"
unspecified
```

**What should I do to make sure that `load-theme` works as expected in batch mode, and in particular that face attributes are the same as in interactive mode?**